# Can .NET assemblies signed with PublicSign be later real-signed?

Tags: c#, .net, strongname, assembly-signing, delay-sign

Can the new [PublicSign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/publicsign-compiler-option) C# compiler option be used instead of [DelaySign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/delay-sign-assembly)? Will it like `DelaySign` allow later to real sign/Authenticode-sign the assembly?

Are there scenarios where you must revert to `DelaySign` and can't use `PublicSign`? I found one scenario is when your project has a `<COMReference>`, the `ResolveComReference` task fails because `DelaySign` is false, but the `.snk` file doesn't have the private key: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/4317

Comment: "Can the new PublicSign C# compiler option be used instead of DelaySign?" I don't see why not. "Will it like DelaySign allow later to real sign/Authenticode-sign the assembly?" the documentation you linked to says it does. "Are there scenarios where you must revert to DelaySign and can't use PublicSign? " well, you found one, so there are probably others, but open-ended questions as that one aren't on-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I couldn't find the place in the documentation where it says that Public Signed assembly reserves space to allow real-signing later? Did I miss it?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this. `sn -R` will real-sign a public-signed assembly so long as you use the private key for the *same* public key it was public-signed with. If you use a different private key, it will refuse.